# Rails: How to handle belongs_to using nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a nested resource as follows:

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments
end
```

And I visit /posts/1/comments/new, what's the best way of setting the post_id on the Comment model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`form_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-namespaces):

```
<%= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
```

Alternatively, you can use the longform:

```
<%= form_for @comment, url: post_comments_path(@post) do |f| %>
```

It will set the url correctly for you.

Your controller actions should look like this:

```
def new
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build
end

def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
  if @comment.save
  ...
end
```

Comment: What should my controller look like?

Comment: @rob_mccann it's that `@post.comments.build` that will automatically set the `post_id` for you on the comment model :)